# Zend_Db_Table_Select_Exception

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

Recieved this error from the below method?

`2013-10-02T14:20:05+01:00 ERR (3): exception 'Zend_Db_Table_Select_Exception' with      message 'Select query cannot join with another table' in /usr/share/php/Zend/Db/Table/Select.php:215`

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Provenir extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
    protected $_name = 'provenir_instance_response';
    protected $_primary = 'provenir_response_id';
    protected $_sequence = true;

    /**
    * Get passed result and check ID
    * @param string $memId
    * @return Zend_Db_Table
    */
    public function scoreCardQuery($memId){
        //Build Query
        $select = $this->select();
        $select->from('scorecard_results', array('passed', 'check_id'));
        $select->where('traveller_id=?', $memId);
        return $this->fetchAll($select);
    }
}
```

There is no join there? :S

Is it because I am referencing `provenir_instance_response` as the DB table in the class argument butI am trying select from `scorecard_results`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Get passed result and check ID
 * @param string $memId
 * @return Zend_Db_Table
 */
public function scoreCardQuery($memId){
    //Build Query
    $select = $this->select();
    $select->setIntegrityCheck(false); //Must be set for this query to work
    $select->from('scorecard_results', array('passed', 'check_id'));
    $select->where('traveller_id=?', $memId);
    return $this->fetchAll($select);
}
```